# How can switch user when login to ubuntu server

Tags: 18.04, directory, users

**Question:**

How can I switch user automatically when I log in to an `Ubuntu18.04` server?

**For example:**
I want to switch from `ubuntu` user to `new_user` user:

```
# from
ubuntu@myserver:~$

# to
new_user@myserver:~/some_dir$
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `ssh new_user@myserver`?

Comment: actually this is a really interesting question and i do not know why! what I can say is that everyone has its own user and we usually work with project_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To truly switch user ID use:

`$ sudo -s -u new_user`

or

`$ su --login new_user`

If you only need to switch your current directory:

`$ cd ~new_user`

To do this automatically at login add the commands to ~ubuntu/.bashrc